# React App working localhost, blank after deployment on firebase

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase

I created my first React-App. The app itself works well. I use firebase.
On localhost everything works, but when I deploy to the hosting, the page is blank, with ZERO errors.
I had one error 'Error on manifest.json' that I corrected but now nothing, and still blank.

I have zero ideas of where the problem come from.

Comment: Boss, give more information if you want to be helped. Which hosting are you using? How do we know? Anything suggested here will technically just be guesses. In any case, My guess is that you did not include your firebase API keys for connection when doing your hosting. Maybe. Just maybe. Again there's no way for us to know.

Comment: @itwabi Hello ! Thanks for you answer. I was using firebase free hosting. Everything was set up completely - this is why I haven't wrote about it, mybad - but I found the error and wrote it, in case someone has the same stupid error :)

Comment: Thanks for actually taking the time to write the answer. Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem was actually very stupid.
On the firebase.src on my root folder I added :

```
"hosting": {
  "public": "build"
}
```

And it worked. It wasn't specified so it add nothing to deploy. Strange I had no info, I checked the deploy logs and found out there was no folder specified being deployed.